# Input type="checkbox" Broken on HTML Mailer that sends on outlook

Tags: html, outlook, mailer

Trying to send an email with a fake checkbox which works on gmail but broken when receive with outlook

```html
<td style="width: 18px; text-align: center; height: 33px;"><span style="font-size: 18px; color: #000000;"><input id="Practice Account" name="interest" type="checkbox" value="Practice Account" /> <label for="Practice Account">Practice Account</label></span></td>
```

on Gmail: [gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeUCX.png)

on Outlook: [outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvfGQ.png)

Anyone knows what's missing in the html? or if its even possible to fix?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Outlook has zero support for styling lists - so no using images for bullets or even declaring a specific list-style-type for Outlook readers. So a checkbox in a form is not going to work.

- https://litmus.com/community/learning/8-outlook-overview

What you could do is to place the form on a web page for people with Outlook. Build the form in email for modern email clients, then wrap it in a conditional statement which hides it from Outlook:

```
<!--[if !mso]>
*survey form*
<![endif]-->
```

Create a second conditional specifically for Outlook:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
*A link to a web page for Outlook users*
<![endif]-->
```

Now the form can be used by most of the popular email clients in use.

Good luck.

Comment: Because NOTHING will work for you in Outlook. This is a solution that can move you forward, but obviously you'll ignore that.

Comment: Move me forward? I tried this solution, I didn't ignore, nothing displayed when I do as you explained